# Call the current user in application controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi guys I am very new to rails and if my question is pretty simple or dumb, please understand me. I am currently using `devise` gem and I tried to put modal in my `application.html.erb` so that the modal always appears on the top but the error message I got is,

> undefined local variable or method `current_user' for ApplicationController:Class

Where should I fix to call the records from the `Post.rb` in `Application.html.erb`? Appreciate your help!

**Application.html.erb**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <% if user_signed_in? %> 
     <li><%=link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete' %></li>
     <%=render "post_list", post_list: @post_list%> //I tried to call this
<% else %> 
   <li><%=link_to 'Sign in',  new_user_session_path %></li>
   <li><%=link_to 'Sign up',  new_user_registration_path %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

**Application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  @post_list = Post.where(user_id: current_user).list?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you really calling `@post_list = Post.where(user_id: current_user).list?` outside an instance method?

Also, did you follow the instructions from Devise? I think you are missing at least one `before_action` to actually perform the user login. `before_action :authenticate_user!`

Comment: You mean if I am calling it in the view?

Comment: In the controller. The statement where you set `@post_list` I suspect you should be calling it inside an instance method. Could you update your question with ALL the code from your controller?

Comment: Ahhh that’s all in the ‘application controller’ tho..

Comment: Ok, then you are missing a few methods... Read the part *Controller filters and helpers* in the [devise page](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br). It's also weird that you dont have the statement  `before_action :protect_from_forgery`  in your `ApplicationController`

Comment: `current_user` will not be available unless it's used inside a `method` or `before_action`. And like @gasc has mentioned append that line in `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was you can access `current_user` in `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user_posts?
    @post_list = Post.where(user_id: current_user).list? // current_user should work here.
  end

end
```