# Check user's permissions prior to granting access, using Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm not sure if there's a better way to go about this, but I was planning on implementing some basic access controls within my Rails application. What I'd like to do is check for the `current_user`, see which company they belong to, and from there, determine if they have access to what they're trying to navigate to. Their company `has_many` associations, so navigating up to the company based on the `current_user` and going from there was my logic.

There's one problem that I'm running to, however: I can't access the `current_user` variable from the `ApplicationController.` It's simply not defined.

According to some suggestions made here [Access devise current_user variable in rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147729/access-devise-current-user-variable-in-rails-controller), I could just add `before_action :authenticate_user!`, but that's already in my `ApplicationController`. Additionally, trying to call `user_signed_in?` doesn't work either because that is an undefined method.

What I don't understand is why I can call the `authenticate_user!` method with `before_action`, but after that it doesn't give me access to the variables.

Here's my Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    attributes = [:first_name, :last_name, :email]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: attributes)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: attributes)
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully signed out."
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Why can't I access the `current_user` method even after the `authenticate_user!` method is called?

I guess an alternative would be to add separate functions into each individual controller to check if the user has access to the object in that controller, but that seems like it could turn into a nightmare.

### Edit

This is where I called `current_user` and `user_signed_in?`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  binding.pry

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    attributes = [:first_name, :last_name, :email]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: attributes)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: attributes)
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully signed out."
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Where I placed a binding.pry, I tried to call it manually from the Rails console once the application paused, but it mentioned it was not available.

Comment: It should be possible to call `user_signed_in?` and `current_user` - Update your code to show where exactly you call these methods

Comment: Updated. I called a `binding.pry` to inspect those variables to see if they existed, but they were undefined methods.

Comment: I am not familiar with binding. Put `user_signed_in?` inside a method in `ApplicationController` and it should work.

Comment: Basically, `binding.pry` allows you to stop the code during run-time to inspect variables, etc. So if it's not there when the application is paused, it won't be there afterwards if I understand correctly. I just placed it in the application controller and the view just rendered saying the variable was undefined. `undefined method `user_signed_in?' for ApplicationController:Class`

Comment: From my understanding, `current_user` can only be called inside a method, just define a method and put `current_user` and see if you can access. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234478/4160532). Also, _the view just rendered saying the variable was undefined_ what view, in the controller action that triggers the view? Can you check `current_user` by using `pry` in that action ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna that did the trick. Didn't realize it couldn't be accessed outside of method. Thanks so much for the help!